# How to programmatically set Glow Effect (Size and Color) to Text in PowerPoint?

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I want to set a glow effect for text in PowerPoint. I have found some code online (e.g. here https://www.skphub.com/2007/ppt001.htm) which claims that one can directly set the Glow Size and Color.

But when I tried, I found that I can set the Glow Size but not the Color (it is read-only).

```
    Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWindow.Selection.TextRange2.Font.Glow.Radius = 10 'this works
    Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWindow.Selection.TextRange2.Font.Glow.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0) 'this fails
```

My question is how can I set the Text glow color in PPT (2016 or 2019)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Got it:

use Font.Glow.Color.RBG